# Golang get system language

Tags: go, internationalization

Is there a function for getting the user's system language I can't find it anywhere on the Go site.

To clarify my question i want the current user's system language that means when everything is for example dutch on the system i want to get "dutch" or "nl"

note: the program is made to run on linux, mac and windows

Comment: You should clarify what the underlying system is. (E.g., is this a Windows desktop application, a Linux command line tool, a web application?)

Comment: On Windows you could execute the [`Get-Culture` powershell command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/get-culture?view=powershell-6).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a nice cross-platform library called
[jibber_jabber](https://godoc.org/github.com/cloudfoundry-attic/jibber_jabber)
which looks up for `$LC_ALL` or `$LANG` env variables in Unix systems and, for Windows, loads **Kernel32** and calls some procedures like `GetUserDefaultLocaleName` or `GetSystemDefaultLocaleName` inside.
For Windows, all is done in the
[`getWindowsLocale()`](https://github.com/cloudfoundry-attic/jibber_jabber/blob/bcc4c8345a21301bf47c032ff42dd1aae2fe3027/jibber_jabber_windows.go#L63)
function.
Be advised that Kernel32 library comes built-in in Windows OS kernel.

By the way, should you need to convert locale-format'd language strings like `en_US` and `fr_FR`, you can utilize the
[x/text/language](https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/text/language) and [x/text/language/display](https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/text/language/display)
packages to get fully qualified name of the language.

```golang
lang := "ru_RU"
tag := language.MustParse(lang)

inEng := display.English.Languages()
inTur := display.Turkish.Languages()
inSelf := display.Self

fmt.Println(inEng.Name(tag))
fmt.Println(inSelf.Name(tag))
fmt.Println(inTur.Name(tag))

   // Output:
   // Russian
   // русский
   // Rusça
```

Comment: Thx that package did the job

Answer (score 3):

One approach would be to try the following strategies in sequence:

1. See if the `LANG` environment variable is set and use that value (common on UNIX systems).
2. Execute powershell on Windows and extract the [`Get-Culture` "Name" property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/get-culture?view=powershell-6).

For example:

```
func main() {
  locale, err := GetLocale()
  fmt.Printf("OK: locale=%q, err=%v\n", locale, err)
  // OK: locale="en-US", err=nil
}

func GetLocale() (string, error) {
  // Check the LANG environment variable, common on UNIX.
  // XXX: we can easily override as a nice feature/bug.
  envlang, ok := os.LookupEnv("LANG")
  if ok {
    return strings.Split(envlang, ".")[0], nil
  }

  // Exec powershell Get-Culture on Windows.
  cmd := exec.Command("powershell", "Get-Culture | select -exp Name")
  output, err := cmd.Output()
  if err == nil {
    return strings.Trim(string(output), "\r\n"), nil
  }

  return "", fmt.Errorf("cannot determine locale")
}
```

Doing these actions in this sequence is convenient because it lets you easily change the locale (e.g. for testing) and should work on both UNIX and Windows operating systems.

Answer (score 2):

On unix-like systems (Mac OS, Linux) you can use the os package to get environment variables with [LookupEnv](https://golang.org/pkg/os/#LookupEnv). So for example you could get the system language/encoding with:

```
s, ok := os.LookupEnv("LANG")
println(s, err)
=> en_US.UTF-8 true
```

There's also a blog article which may be of interest to you on the golang.org blog (more about choosing languages once you know the system language setting):

https://blog.golang.org/matchlang

On windows you might be able to use this package to get the language from the registry if the above doesn't work (I'd try os.LookupEnv first).

https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/sys/windows/registry

Comment: thx that helped me somewhat for linux and mac but it also needs to work on windows

Answer (score 2):

I improved the @maerics answer to support MacOS too:

```golang
func getLocale() (string, string) {
    osHost := runtime.GOOS
    defaultLang := "en"
    defaultLoc := "US"
    switch osHost {
    case "windows":
        // Exec powershell Get-Culture on Windows.
        cmd := exec.Command("powershell", "Get-Culture | select -exp Name")
        output, err := cmd.Output()
        if err == nil {
            langLocRaw := strings.TrimSpace(string(output))
            langLoc := strings.Split(langLocRaw, "-")
            lang := langLoc[0]
            loc := langLoc[1]
            return lang, loc
        }
    case "darwin":
        // Exec shell Get-Culture on MacOS.
        cmd := exec.Command("sh", "osascript -e 'user locale of (get system info)'")
        output, err := cmd.Output()
        if err == nil {
            langLocRaw := strings.TrimSpace(string(output))
            langLoc := strings.Split(langLocRaw, "_")
            lang := langLoc[0]
            loc := langLoc[1]
            return lang, loc
        }
    case "linux":
        envlang, ok := os.LookupEnv("LANG")
        if ok {
            langLocRaw := strings.TrimSpace(envlang)
            langLocRaw = strings.Split(envlang, ".")[0]
            langLoc := strings.Split(langLocRaw, "_")
            lang := langLoc[0]
            loc := langLoc[1]
            return lang, loc
        }
    }
    return defaultLang, defaultLoc
}

func main() {
    lang, loc := getLocale()
    fmt.Printf("OK: language=%s, locale=%s", lang, loc)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

### For Windows

powerShell.[Get-Culture](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/get-culture?view=powershell-7.2)

```
> Get-Culture
LCID             Name             DisplayName
----             ----             -----------
1033             en-US            English (United States)
```

and you can use `syscall.SysProcAttr{HideWindow: true}` to hide the window.

### Example

##### get_lang.go

```golang
package main

import (
    "io"
    "log"
    "os"
    "os/exec"
    "strings"
    "syscall"
)

func GetLocale(defaultLang, defaultLoc string) (lang string, loc string) {
    cmd := exec.Command("powershell", "Get-Culture | select -exp Name")
    cmd.SysProcAttr = &syscall.SysProcAttr{HideWindow: true} // Hide the window, so you will not see the window flash of PowerShell.
    output, err := cmd.Output()
    if err == nil {
        langLocRaw := strings.TrimSpace(string(output))
        langLoc := strings.Split(langLocRaw, "-")
        return langLoc[0], langLoc[1]
    }
    return defaultLang, defaultLoc
}

func main() {
    lang, loc := GetLocale("en", "US")
    logFile, _ := os.OpenFile("output.log", os.O_APPEND|os.O_CREATE|os.O_WRONLY, 0666)
    logger := log.New(io.MultiWriter(logFile, os.Stdout), "", log.Lmsgprefix)
    logger.Printf("language=%s\nlocale=%s\n", lang, loc)
}
```

> go build -ldflags "-H=windowsgui -s -w" get_lang.go

And run `get_lang.exe`

Output results:

- No windows will pop out
- output the result to the logfile